# Why does docker-compose launch different image when run with the '-p' flag

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have a setup with our Jenkins server running within a Docker container which I have taken over from a colleague who has left.
I am seeing some behaviour which I do not understand and have not been able to work out what is going on from the documentation.
My folder structure looks like this:

```
└── Master
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    └── jenkins-master
        └── Dockerfile
```

My docker-compose.yaml file looks like this (this is just a snippet of the relevant part):

```
version: '3'

services:
  master:
    build: ./jenkins-master
```

I have updated the version of the base Jenkins image in `jenkins-master/Dockerfile` and then rebuilt using `docker-compose build`.
This succeeds and results in an image called `master_master`
If I run `docker images` I see this new image as well as a previous image:

```
REPOSITORY        TAG      IMAGE ID    CREATED          SIZE
master_master     latest   <id1>       16 hours ago     704MB
jenkins_master    latest   <id2>       10 months ago    707MB
```

As I understand it, the name `master_master` is as a result of the base folder name (i.e. `Master`) and the service name of `master` in the `docker-compose.yaml` file.
I don't know how the existing image ended up with the name `jenkins_master`. Would the folder name have had to be `Jenkins` rather than `Master`, or is there another way that would have resulted in this name?

When I run `docker-compose up -d` it uses the `master_master` image to launch a container (called `master_master_1`).

When I run `docker-compose -p jenkins up -d` it uses the `jenkins_master` image to launch a container (called `jenkins_master_1`).

Apart from the different container names, the resultant running containers are different as I can see that the Jenkins versions are different (as per the change I made in the Dockerfile).
I do not change the docker-compose file at all between running these 2 commands and yet different images are run.

The documentation that I have found for specifying the -p (--project-name) flag states:

> Sets the project name. This value is prepended along with the service
> name to the container on start up. For example, if your project name
> is `myapp` and it includes two services `db` and `web`, then Compose
> starts containers named `myapp_db_1` and `myapp_web_1` respectively.
>
> Setting this is optional. If you do not set this, the
> `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` defaults to the `basename` of the project
> directory.

There is nothing that leads me to believe that the `-p` flag will result in a different image being run.

So what is going on here?
How does docker-compose choose which image to run?
Is this happening due to the names of the images `master_master` vs `jenkins_master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use the `docker-compose -p` option, you need to use it with every `docker-compose` command, including `docker-compose build`.

If your `docker-compose.yml` file doesn't specify an `image:`, Compose constructs an image name from the current *project* name and the Compose service name.  The project name and Docker object metadata are the only way it has to remember anything.  So what's happening here is that the plain `docker-compose build` builds the image for the `master` service in the `master` project, but then `docker-compose -p jenkins up` looks for the `master` service in the `jenkins` project, and finds the other image.

```
docker-compose -p jenkins build
docker-compose -p jenkins up -d
```

It may or may not be easier to set the [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) environment variable, possibly putting this in a [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/).  In a Jenkins context, I also might consider using [Jenkins's Docker integration](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) to build (and push) the image, and only referring to `image:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add **image** option in the docker-compose.yml file. It will create the container with a specified docker image.

```
build: ./jenkins-master
image: dockerimage_name:tag
```

Comment: I appreciate the response and I understand what this will do but this doesn't answer my question. I am trying to understand why docker-compose is running 2 different images just because I specify the -p flag. I would've thought that it would run the same image but then name the containers differently.